# Unable to upload image

Tags: 2010, html, image

I have uploaded an image to use as a banner across multiple pages in an image library. 
I use HTML to center the image on each page and to "src=""" the image. 
I want to upload/replace this banner, but everytime I upload the new image and open it, it is the same old image. This is really frustrating as id rather not change the "src=""" in the html on each page to accomodate a name change.
Does anyone know why this is happening? Is there a fix? Am I the only one experiencing this?

The image I am uploading is significantly different, upload is succesfull, but its just the same old image.

Comment: Have you made sure the file is published? In the image library

Comment: Yes its there exactly as it should be, but the image is still the same. Ive had this problem before, but eventually it went away after 1-2 tries. This time it seems like its here to stay.

Comment: As Robert mentioned. Do you got publishing infrastructure enabled? Is the new picture name the same as the old picture? Then you need to publish a major version of the last picture.

Comment: Versioning is disabled in this library.
The picture names are identical though.

Comment: But you do have the publishing infrastructure feature activated, correct?

Comment: SharePoint Server Publishing not activated

Comment: did you hardcode the url or the image?

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed really similar problems with images and I ended up solving it by changing the name of the new image.

Somehow if I made modifications to the image or changed it and replaced the old one with it while keeping the same name, the old image was still shown around insted of the new one. Don't know why it's happening, but I suspect it might be because of some cache bug or delay.

I hope this helps! :-)

Comment: It could very well be the output cache that does this, depending on how the image tag is rendered